# Jquery ajax and Rails 3 -> load content

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a beginner with ajax. I have a slider and a content div, the slider has links (event, news etc.), I want to create ajax load to content div (like Facebook).
I used Google, but I found very old articles (rails 2, but I use rails3).
In Rails 3 tutorial book has jQuery ajax with rails3, but it's very tiny.

I'am at this point:
I setting up my form with remote tag (:remote => true), and I renamed new.html.haml to _new.html.haml partial. I think I must create a new.js.erb file, which contains:

```
$(".menuitem").load("<%= escape_javascript(render('article/new')) %>") .content"); //just an idea
```

Is my logic is right?
If you have a good tutorial or example about rails and ajax, please share with me.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest would be to load your `.content` element `onclick` using jQuery:

```
$(".menuitem").click(function() {
  $(".content").load("/articles/new");
});
```

and render the form partial in your controller:

```
def new
  render :partial => 'form'
end
```

Answer (score 9):

I'd reccomand using `jquery_ujs` to handle this.

With Rails 3.1+, simply add `gem 'jquery-rails'` to your gemfile and `//= require jquery_ujs` in your `application.js` header.

Seting your links with `:remote => true` will then call the href using Ajax.

To load a blog post into your `#content` div you can then create a show_post.js.erb to render your post (assuming `show_post` is the action you use and you have a "_content_post.html.haml" that display the blog post content) :

`$('#content').html('<%= escape_javascript (render :partial => "content_post") %>')`

hope this help

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create a file for **create.js.erb** or **create.js.haml** because it's the action being processed.

Here's a good tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

**Note:** The article has an error where the call to **escape_javascript** has the **S** in script capitalized.

Comment: Thanks for the link! However, I'd go a step further and say that readers should install the JQuery gem, via the "install" instructions here: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs.  Also, before installing the gem, remove the "config.action_view.javascript..." line from your application.rb file, since the gem does not need it.